# Wordpress plugin enqueue scripts working for js, but not css files

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to load custom css specifically relevant to the plugin. The js is working perfectly fine, but the css just refuses to get loaded in. Here is the code:

```
function admin_plugin_scripts(){

  wp_enqueue_style('arena', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/arena.css',
                    array(), filemtime( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . 
                   '/PluginName/css/arena.css'), true  );

  wp_enqueue_script('admin', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/admin.js',
                     array('jquery'),
                     filemtime( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . 
                     '/PluginName/js/admin.js' ), true); 

  wp_localize_script( 'admin', 'ajaxobj',
                      array('ajax_url' =>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_plugin_scripts');
```

Thanks in advance for any help offered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) last argument is the `$media` and you set it to true so its mean you are doing

```
<link rel='stylesheet' ... media='1' />
```

> $media (string) (Optional) The media for which this stylesheet has been defined. Accepts media types like **'all', 'print' and 'screen', or media queries like '(orientation: portrait)' and '(max-width: 640px)'**.
>
> Default value: 'all'

So you should or remove the last argument so it will be the default **all** or just set some other media type.

```
wp_enqueue_style('arena', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/arena.css',
                array(), filemtime( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . 
               '/PluginName/css/arena.css') );
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! yeah I should have double checked that parameter ...  0_0